# How to update bashrc to auto add ssh credentials for git

Tags: git

I was wondering if there was a way to have the bashrc auto add your credentials for git.

When I use git bash I always have to do the 'ssh-add C:/Users/.../... then add password after, before I start anything.

Is there a way where I can set up that file to auto add that info? Or just any way in general, bashrc looked like the place to attack however I am not sure.

Current bashrc is this:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/environment"

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "$SSH_ENV"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "$SSH_ENV"
    . "$SSH_ENV" > /dev/null
    ssh-add
}

# test for identities
function test_identities {
    # test whether standard identities have been added to the agent already
    ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        ssh-add
        # $SSH_AUTH_SOCK broken so we start a new proper agent
        if [ $? -eq 2 ];then
            start_agent
        fi
    fi
}

start_agent
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the best way to achieve what you are asking is to have your SSH keys  managed by an SSH agent. On a Linux box I'd use `keychain` to achieve this, but it looks like you're using Windows.